# custom object in javascript to add two digits

Tags: javascript, object

how to make a object which has a simple method to add two digits in javascript

```
 calc.sum(1,2);
```

here calc is an object with sum method which takes two parameters and return the value as 3.

Comment: please explain it also

Answer (score 1):

```
var calc = { sum : function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
   } 
};
```

Now call it using:

```
var test = calc.sum(1,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

the basic concept is

```
var calc = {};
calc.sum = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

As well you can do:

```
var createCalc = (function(){
   var sum = function(a, b) {
       return a+b;
   };
   return {
       sum : sum
   } 
});
var cal = createCalc();
```

or

```
function Calc() {
  this.sum = function(a, b) {
           return a+b;
  };
}

var calc = new Calc( );
```

I always recommend this github with patterns.
http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/#object-creation-patterns

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the object like so:

```
var calc = 
    { 
        sum : function(a,b){ return a + b; }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var calc={
   sum:function(1,b){
       return a+b;
   }
}
```

Now you can  use this method

```
 var value = calc.sum(1,3)
```

> //value = 4